# Symfony: question about paths

Tags: symfony1

in the cover page (login, register...) of my app i have this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/formularios.css">
```

When i deploy my app, the that css rule is not loaded because, as i can
see in Firebug, it's looking for that rules in
www.tirengarfio.com/css/formularios.css instead of
www.tiregarfio.com/rs2/web/css/formularios.css.

What should i do?

Javi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `view.yml` config file and the `include_stylesheets()` helper. However, if you'd like to create the link tags by hand, use the `public_path()` helper to get the correct path.